# populate datagridview with another datagridview selected row c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm looking for the best way to populate my datagridview with selected rows from another datagridview by checkbox.

```
DataGridViewRow Row = new DataGridViewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            Row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Row.Cells[0].Value) == true) //cell 0 contain checkbox
            {
                //i stacked here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```